# Angular Reactive forms : change vs valueChanges

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-observable

I am using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in Angular 7.

I have many fields that are dependent on other fields.

What I am curious about of what should I use `(change)` or `this.form.get("control_name").valueChanges`?

For ex. if both will work on inputs then I want to know difference, pros & cons between them.

Which is better with performance?

Answer (score 31):

Let's just consider that what you're looking for is to listen to a change on an `input` tag of `type="text"`

#### In case of `valueChanges`

Since it is an Observable, it will fire with a new value. This value will be the changed value of the `input` field. And to listen to it, you will have to `subscribe` to the `valueChanges` Observable. Something like this:

```
this.form1.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
  console.log(change); // Value inside the input field as soon as it changes
});
```

#### In the case of `(change)` event

In case of the `change` event, for `input` tag, the `change` event will **only fire once you `blur` away** from that `input` field. Also, in this case, you'll get the `$event` Object. And from that `$event` Object, you'll have to extract the field value.

---

So in code, this will look something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  form1: FormGroup;
  form2: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form1 = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      email: []
    });

    this.form2 = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      email: []
    });

    this.form1.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
      console.log(change);
    });
  }

  onForm2NameChange({ target }) {
    console.log(target.value);
  }

}
```

And in the Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form1">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  <input type="text" formControlName="email">
</form>

<hr>

<form [formGroup]="form2">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" (change)="onForm2NameChange($event)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="email">
</form>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-vs-value-changes?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

---

**NOTE:** It completely depends on your use case as to which one would be more suitable.

---

#### UPDATE:

For your specific use case, I would suggest using RxJS Operators to get the job done. Something like this:

```
zipCodeFormControl
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(
      zipcode => getAddressFromZipcode(zipcode)
    ),
    map(res => res.actualResult)
  )
  .subscribe(addressComponents => {
    // Here you can extract the specific Address Components
    // that you want to auto fill in your form and call the patchValue method on your form or the controls individually
  });
```

Comment: That is the point. At this point i am creating forms. I am confused what should i use.

Comment: With the information so far, I think as far as the performance goes, `(change)` would be better as it gets called only once you `blur` away from the field. But again. without a more concrete example, it's hard to determine. Maybe create an example that can highlight the issue that you're facing and maybe I would be able to give better suggestions.

Comment: I just have input of zip. On it's change i have to call service to get data like state, country, city...

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya, I've updated my answer. Please check to see if that works for your use case.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to use Reactive Forms logic only. If you need to have a behaviour like `(change)` has, so that the value should only be emitted when blur is executed, you can set `updateOn: 'blur'` like this:

```
    this.fb.group({
      title: this.fb.control('', { updateOn: 'blur' }),
      description: '',
    })
```

or like this for the whole form:

```
    this.fb.group({
      title: '',
      description: '',
    },{updateOn: 'blur'})
```

Now you can subscribe to valueChanges:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(change=>{ console.log(change) })
```

In the first example, this will log changes in description every time you type something and for title only on leaving the input field.

Comment: this is the right answer as the Angular documentation states that the source of truth for reactive forms is the model  `this.fb.group(...)` while for template driven forms is the template.

Answer (score 3):

This is case-to-case, but I find that things like checkboxes and radio buttons (true/false type controls) work better with the (change) handler and inputs and textfields are generally more suitable for valueChanges.

Although I'm not sure of performance, I assume this would be the ideal use case when dealing with this decision.

A good use case for valueChanges (for everything) is a complex form with a lot of ngIf logic. Sometimes these forms need a "chain reaction" of value changes to work correctly, in which case a (change) handler would be useless

Answer (score 1):

In case of an input (text) field, I would suggest to use either `changeValues` or `value` depending on your use case:

- If you want to implement something similar to  "Google's autocomplete feature", i.e., to provide (search) suggestions as you type → then use `changeValues`.
- For every other case, I would use `change`.

This is just a rule of thumb, though, the devil is in the details.

Here is the code of a working example which I wrote while doing my own research/testing, it implements both approaches for the sake of comparison:

- [component HTML file](https://github.com/VictorGil/transfers_frontend/blob/f2cb000ad1f34810ca4d658afa05f1ee4e8967ac/src/app/account-balance-form/account-balance-form.component.html)
- [component TypeScript file](https://github.com/VictorGil/transfers_frontend/blob/f2cb000ad1f34810ca4d658afa05f1ee4e8967ac/src/app/account-balance-form/account-balance-form.component.ts)