# Want to hide the input div but not the functionality in angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Below is the html, to scan the bar-coder and the same will assign to *barCodeNumber* variable,
onChange() function will call once the bar-coder scanned,

**Question**:-
I want to hide the div from UI, but the function should work, even div is not visible.

I tried using "visibility: hidden" in scss style class, but the function is not working.

```
<div class="mt-5">
    <div class=" flex flex-row align-content-center justify-content-between row-gap-6 card-container">
        <form>
                <input type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="barCodeNumber"
                    autofocus="true" placeholder="Enter/Scan RFID" (change)="mappingFunction($event)">
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

below is .ts file:

```
mappingFunction(event){
console.log('Event print', event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [Angular Reactive forms : change vs valueChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300119/angular-reactive-forms-change-vs-valuechanges)

tldr:

- (change) is called when blured away (which doesn't happen if it's hidden)
- valueChanges is called every time and as soon as the value changes.

Also there is a special type of input that's hidden

```
<input type="hidden" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "get out" from view the input

```
style {
   position:absolute;
   top:-3rem;
}
```